# sweet pages jquery prev / next buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination

Got a problem with Sweet Pages pagination as it works really well but doesn't have a previous / next buttons to move pages (slides).

Here's a tutorial that I've found: http://tutorialzine.com/2010/05/sweet-pages-a-jquery-pagination-solution/

I tried to get that working but I guess I'm doing something wrong. 
Here's my approach:

```
$("#prev11").click( function()
       {
         swControls.append('<a href="" class="swShowPage">'+(i-1)+'</a>');
       }
    );
$("#next11").click( function()
       {
         swControls.append('<a href="" class="swShowPage">'+(i+1)+'</a>');
       }
    );
```

Comment: can you share the complete code?

Comment: here's the code: http://jsfiddle.net/1kdpdr4L/

Comment: Please update HTML and CSS too

Comment: Just updated all the things so you see a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/1kdpdr4L/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've update the `$.sweetPage` plugin.

I added `next` and `prev` option, strings that represent the selector for the next/prev buttons.

So you need to init the plugin like:

```
$('#holder').sweetPages({perPage:6, next: '#next', prev: '#prev'});
```

As you see in the HTML, are two buttons with the id `#next` and `#prev`.

**How works?**

```
$(opts.next).click(function(e) {
    $('.swShowPage.active').next('.swShowPage').click();
});
```

`$(opts.next) = $('#next')` is clicked we search for the next dot after the 'active' dot and simulate click.

The same process is using for the previous button.

```
$(opts.prev).click(function(e) {
    $('.swShowPage.active').prev('.swShowPage').click();
});
```

**In action:** https://jsfiddle.net/1kdpdr4L/3/

Comment: Great! That's what I was looking for.